# What does "x(n) is complex" mean? (DSP)

Tags: discrete-signals

I am new to EE area and I met a question in my homework:
[image]

Can someone help me a little bit? I think it is quite easy!

Thanks!!

Comment: It means they can take complex values.

Comment: @MBaz, [Short answers are still answers :)](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1426/should-short-answers-be-comments-or-answers) (This question cannot be closed as off-topic, unclear or too-broad, so if not closed as answered it will be circulating for ever :/ ).

Comment: @A_A I hope you don't mind: I edit your comment to link to meta. :-)

Comment: @A_A  I didn't put it as an answer since I thought I had misunderstood the question :)

Answer (score 4):

It means that $x(n)$ and $y(n)$ can be complex numbers rather than just real numbers. As a result there is no conjugate symmetry in the Frequency domain for these signals. Note that part (c) the asterisk in $x^*(n)$ usually means to take the complex conjugate. If $x(n)$ and $y(n)$ were real, i.e. not complex, then (b) and (c) would be equivalent.